# Google Table Chart Number Formatting displays NaN when using formatted numeric value with comma's

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

As often happens whenever Google has a major release of their charts library       things break.  The following code was implemented about 3 years ago and worked fine for a couple of years and within the last year it broke this way

I populate a Data Table and format the numbers with this code

```
            var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern:'#,###.##'});

        var cl = jsonChartData.rows[0].c.length;
        for (var c=0;c<cl;c++) {
            if (jsonChartData.cols[c].type == 'number'){
                formatter.format(popDataTable, c);
            }
        }
```

and this works well and produces a result like this: `v: 6155177.2549019605,  f: '6,155,177.25'`

And is supported by documentation here [Google Table Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#data-format), here [Generic formatters](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters), and here [ICU 58.1](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html#_details)

I populate the view that is passed to the chart object using the following code

```
            var tabOpt = {
                width: '100%'
                ,allowHtml: true
                ,cssClassNames: {
                    tableRow: 'chartTabRow'
                    ,oddTableRow: 'chartTabRow'
                    ,headerRow: 'chartHeadRow'
                    ,tableCell: 'chartTabRow'
                    ,headerCell: 'chartHeadRow'
                    }
                };
        var wdt = popDataTable;
        wdt.sort([
            {column: colID(wdt, 'sumlev')}
            ,{column: colID(wdt, 'estyear')}
            ,{column: colID(wdt, 'estdata')}
            ,{column: popFactCol, desc:  true}]);
        dView = new google.visualization.DataView(wdt);
        dView.setRows(dView.getFilteredRows([
            {column: colID(dView, 'sumlev'), value: '010'}
            ,{column: colID(dView, 'estdata'), value: popFact}
            ,{column: colID(dView, 'estyear'), value: popFactYear}]));

        var jsonPopParams = {
          "cols":
              [
              {"id":"","label":"Parameter(N)","pattern":"","type":"string"},
              {"id":"","label":"Value","pattern":"","type":"number"}
              ]
              ,
              "rows":
              [
                {"c":
                [
                {"v":"N","f":null},
                {"v":0,"f":null}
                ]
                },
                {"c":
                [
                {"v":"Sum","f":null},
                {"v":0,"f":null}
                ]
                },
                {"c":
                [
                {"v":"Min","f":null},
                {"v":0,"f":null}
                ]
                },
                {"c":
                [
                {"v":"Max","f":null},
                {"v":0,"f":null}
                ]
                },
                {"c":
                [
                {"v":"Range","f":null},
                {"v":0,"f":null}
                ]
                },
               {"c":
                [
                {"v":"Mean","f":null},
                {"v":0,"f":null}
                ]
                },
               {"c":
                [
                {"v":"Median","f":null},
                {"v":0,"f":null}
                ]
                },
               {"c":
                [
                {"v":"Variance","f":null},
                {"v":0,"f":null}
                ]
                },
               {"c":
                [
                {"v":"Standard Dev","f":null},
                {"v":0,"f":null}
                ]
                },
               {"c":
                [
                {"v":"Skewness","f":null},
                {"v":0,"f":null}
                ]
                },
               {"c":
                [
                {"v":"Kurtosis","f":null},
                {"v":0,"f":null}
                ]
                }]
              ,
              "p":null
              };

        jsonPopParams.rows[0].c[1].f = dView.getFormattedValue(0, colID(dView, 'pn'));
        jsonPopParams.rows[1].c[1].f = dView.getFormattedValue(0, colID(dView, 'psum'));
        jsonPopParams.rows[2].c[1].f = dView.getFormattedValue(0, colID(dView, 'pmin'));
        jsonPopParams.rows[3].c[1].f = dView.getFormattedValue(0, colID(dView, 'pmax'));
        jsonPopParams.rows[4].c[1].f = dView.getFormattedValue(0, colID(dView, 'prange'));
        jsonPopParams.rows[5].c[1].f = dView.getFormattedValue(0, colID(dView, 'pmean'));
        jsonPopParams.rows[6].c[1].f = dView.getFormattedValue(0, colID(dView, 'pmedian'));
        jsonPopParams.rows[7].c[1].f = dView.getFormattedValue(0, colID(dView, 'pvariance'));
        jsonPopParams.rows[8].c[1].f = dView.getFormattedValue(0, colID(dView, 'pstndev'));
        jsonPopParams.rows[9].c[1].f = dView.getFormattedValue(0, colID(dView, 'pskew'));
        jsonPopParams.rows[10].c[1].f = dView.getFormattedValue(0, colID(dView, 'pkurt'));

        var tblChart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById(paramDiv));
        wdt = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonPopParams);
        var tblView = new google.visualization.DataView(wdt);
        tblChart.draw(tblView, tabOpt);
```

Setting a break point and stepping though each instruction, I can see that for formatted value is getting populated in the JSON object jsonPopParams.

So for example pmean has a formatted value of `'6,155,177.25'`

When the chart is rendered, any value that has a comma in the formatting displays an NaN.

[I created a working pared down example in JS Fiddle here:](http://jsfiddle.net/threadid/jhpqbzzd)

In there I tested three scenarios

- formatted value has no commas and 2 decimals `###.##` using `view.getFormattedValue` and produces 6,155,177.25  this of course is the work around
- formatted value has commas and 2 decimals `#,###.##` using `view.getFormattedValue` and produces NaN  what its doing right now
- formatted value has commas and 2 decimals but uses `view.getValue` and produces 6,155,177.255 the default low order positions must be 3... it works but not according to spec.

So I'm not sure if

1) I was doing it wrong before and getting away with it and now Google fixed a root cause and now my wrong code is not working any more

OR

2) Google broke something and now my correct code is not working any more.

Hopefully a second set of eyes with a fresh perspective can see though.

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Updated code example and JSFiddle to assign to correct element `.f` with formatted value.  `jsonPopParams.rows[5].c[1].f = dView.getFormattedValue(0, colID(dView, 'pmean'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem appears to be these lines...

```
jsonPopParams.rows[0].c[1].v = dView.getFormattedValue(0, colID(dView, 'pn'));
jsonPopParams.rows[1].c[1].v = dView.getFormattedValue(0, colID(dView, 'psum'));
....
```

the *value* property (`v`) is being set with the formatted value (`f`)

so it should either be...

```
jsonPopParams.rows[0].c[1].f = dView.getFormattedValue(0, colID(dView, 'pn'));
```

or...

```
jsonPopParams.rows[0].c[1].v = dView.getValue(0, colID(dView, 'pn'));
```

or both...

```
jsonPopParams.rows[0].c[1].v = dView.getValue(0, colID(dView, 'pn'));
jsonPopParams.rows[0].c[1].f = dView.getFormattedValue(0, colID(dView, 'pn'));
```

when the DataTable is created here...

```
var tblChart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById(paramDiv));
wdt = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonPopParams);
....
```

strings are being used instead of numbers,
since the column type is number --> `{"id":"","label":"Value","pattern":"","type":"number"}`
`NaN` is returned

Comment: Yes that is it exactly.  Which makes perfect sense:  Numeric value goes to v (number) and formatted value goes to f (string).  The smaller numbers don't have commas and therefore the number as string could be cast to integer.  The newer version of the library must be enforcing better type safety.  I don't recall from 3 years ago but assigning to v was the working answer.  Thanks